# javascript in SAPUI5 - Require JS initialisation to simple method call or How to import "require js based" lib to SAP Business Objects

Tags: javascript, sapui5, business-objects

Does someone can tell me how to change RequireJS definition:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define([], factory(root));
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = factory(root);
    } else {
        root.someVariable = factory(root);
    }
})(typeof global !== "undefined" ? global : this.window || this.global, function (root) {

    'use strict';

    var $someVariable = {},
        someAnotherVariable = 'bla bla bla',
....
var someFunction = function(someVar) {
}
...
    return $someVariable;
});
```

To something like:

```
var someVariable = callAllInsideAndReturnVariableValue(title, message);
```

In details. Trying to move this JS (https://github.com/dolce/iziToast/blob/master/dist/js/iziToast.js) to simple function call, as described before.

Or might be someone know how to use this JS in SAP UI5? In details in SAP Design Studio (Business Objects)

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution, here is the post how to attach RequireJS lib to DS Component:
https://blogs.sap.com/2016/04/15/your-first-extension-part-13-includejs/

Just in case if someone need such solution as well :)

Comment: What does this blog post have in common with sapui5/openui5? Isn't it about Design Studio?

Comment: Exactly. The same as in question. Because Design Studio has own behaviour. And.. I was not able to find how to adopt it to DS.. later found.

Answer (score 0):

introduce a factory to initialize you module code correctly for others.

```
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define([], factory(root)); //initialized through AMD
} else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
     module.exports = factory(root)//initialized module loader,see:  commonjs
} else {
    root.someVariable = factory(root);//initialize to windows/global
}
```